# React Testing Library waitForElementToBeRemoved not work truely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, frontend, react-testing-library

In my React application, I have a button on the screen which after clicking on it, a specific element in the screen will disappear. By Clicking the button, a state will change and after re-rendering the component, the element will disappear.

To test this scenario, I am using the *React Testing library*. It does not work truly by **waitForElementToBeRemoved** :

```
//element to hide
const listContainer = screen.getByRole('list'); 

//Toggle button
 const queryButton = screen.getByRole('button', {
    name: 'Query',
  })

userEvent.click(queryButton); 

//this line get error: Exceeded timeout of 20000 ms for a test.
await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => listContainer);
```

but when I change waiting the process it works:

```
await waitFor(() => {
    expect(listContainer).not.toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

I don't understand why. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Change your test to use:

```
//Toggle button
const queryButton = screen.getByRole('button', {
 name: 'Query',
})

userEvent.click(queryButton); 

// Use queryByRole instead of getByRole
await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => screen.queryByRole('list'));
```

This should work as `queryByRole` returns null instead of an error if an item is not found. `waitFor` works as it retries until the wrapped function stops throwing an error (which is what `getByRole` does if an element is not found). If the `queryByRole` change still doesn't work for you, you can additionally try incrementing the timeout e.g. `await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => screen.queryByRole('list'), {timeout: 3000);`

More info on the difference between `waitForElementToBeRemoved` and `waitFor` can be found [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-disappearance/#waiting-for-disappearance). Also check out [this](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#using-query-variants-for-anything-except-checking-for-non-existence) article which advises to only use `queryBy...` whenever you need to check for the non-existence of an element.

Comment: unfortunately non of them not work, i read the kent. c. article too. but did not help :(

Comment: Hmmm I'm surprised. What version of userEvent are you using? Are you able to demo your issue in codepen/stackblitz or someother sandbox?

Comment: this is the version: ^12.8.3
unfortunately no, it is not a personal project, but if you had time I can share with you the screen.